# receiving null is not an object (evaluating ' this.state.search')

Tags: javascript, null, react-native

I am receiving null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.search') I am new to react-native so not 100% sure whats going on. thanks for any help.

This is my basic search bar:

```js
use strict';

import React, { Component }                             from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button }    from 'react-native';
import renderIf                                         from '../common/renderIf';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Icon, CardItem, Card, Input, InputGroup} from 'native-base';




export default class SearchBar extends Component {



  render() {
    return (
                <Card> 
                    <CardItem searchBar rounded>                      
                        <InputGroup>
                            <Icon name="ios-search" />
                            <Input placeholder="Search" value={this.state.search} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({search:text})} onSubmitEditing={()=>this.search()}/>
                        </InputGroup>
                    
                    </CardItem>
                </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

This is is to take the inputed text from the search bar and display the results:

```js
'use strict';

import React, { Component }                             from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button }    from 'react-native';
import renderIf                                         from '../common/renderIf';
import { Container, Content, Icon, CardItem, Card, Thumbnail, Title, List, ListItem} from 'native-base';
import { Col, Row, Grid }                               from "react-native-easy-grid";

export default class AddMovieResults extends Component {

    search() {   
    // Set loading to true when the search starts to display a Spinner        
    this.setState({            
        loading: true          
    });

    var that = this;        
    return fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' +this.state.search)       
    .then((response) => response.json())            
    .then((responseJson) => {      
        // Store the results in the state variable results and set loading to                 
         // false to remove the spinner and display the list of repositories                
          that.setState({                    
        results: responseJson,                    
        loading: false                
    });
    return responseJson.Search;            
}) 
    .catch((error) => {
        that.setState({                    
        loading: false                 
    });
        console.error(error);        
    });    
}


  render() {
    return (

                    <Card scrollEnabled={true}> 
                        <CardItem button >  

                           <List dataArray={this.state.results.items} renderRow={(item) =>               
                                <ListItem button >
                                <Row> 

                                  <Col size={1}>
                                    <Thumbnail square style={{ height: 90, width:60, bottom:6,justifyContent: 'center',}} source={{uri: item.poster}} /> 
                                  </Col>  

                                  <Col size={3}>
                                    
                                    <Row size={3}> 
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 25, color: '#DD5044',justifyContent: 'center',}}>{item.title}</Text>      
                                    </Row>

                                    <Row size={1}>
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, color: '#DD5044',}}>{item._year_data}</Text>    
                                   </Row>
                                   
                                   </Col>
                                  </Row>  
                                </ListItem>                            
                            } />
                        </CardItem>
                    </Card> 
    );
  }
}
```

This is my index file which displays the above files on one page:

```js
'use strict';

import React, { Component }                             from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button }    from 'react-native';
import renderIf                                         from '../common/renderIf';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content}             from 'native-base';
import { Col, Row, Grid }                               from "react-native-easy-grid";

import AddMovieResults                                  from './AddMovieResults';
import SearchBar                                        from './SearchBar';


export default class AddNewMovie extends Component {




  render() {
    return (
        <Container scrollEnabled={false}>
            <Header>
                <Title> Add Movie</Title>
            </Header>
            <Content>
        <Grid>
            <Col>
            {/* import search bar */}
                <SearchBar/>
            {/*import search results*/}
                <AddMovieResults/>
            </Col>
        </Grid>
            </Content>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are attempting to invoke `this.search()` in `<SearchBar/>` a component that has no search method... that method invocation will always throw an error

Answer (score 0):

State is not global, it is local to each component so you will need to pass it to the object as a prop.

The problem here however is that as you are defining the search bar and add movie results you will need to find a way to pass the state back from SearchBar.

To accomplish this you can pass a reference function to update the state of AddNewMovie:

Add the following function to your addNewMovie class:

```js
updateAddNewMovieState = (newData) => {
 this.setState({search:newData})
}
```

Next pass it into the search bar class:

```js
<SearchBar
  updateState = {this.updateAddNewMovieState}
  currentState = {this.state.search}
/>
```

Now use this.props.currentState to access the search state and this.props.updateState(newState) to modify the state in AddNewMovie from the search bar class.

Finally, pass the variable through to AddMovieResults:

```js
<AddMovieResults
  search={this.state.search}
/>
```

You can then access the variable in AddMovieResults via this.props.search.

While this method is relatively straight forward it quickly becomes convoluted if you are passing many variables around, for this purpose I recommend https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux which allows you to store variables much cleaner through action functions and reduction states.

I would also recommend defining your state variables in each component constructor to make it much clearer where they are being defined:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      something: "Something"
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind your function in the constructor to be able to access `this` outside of inherited React class functions like `render`, `constructor`, etc...:

```
export default class AddMovieResults extends Component {
    constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    }
    search() {   
    // Set loading to true when the search starts to display a Spinner        
        this.setState({            
            loading: true          
        });
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```